# Doubt on Regular expressions in PHP

Tags: php, regex

Friends,

I have a silly doubt:

Assume that I have a line like this

```
Heading: Value1; SomeText1 (a, b, c), Value 2; SomeText2 (d, e, f)
```

I wanted to remove all semicolon and remove everything in brackets (including brackets). I managed to do this using this code

```
if (strstr($line,'Heading')){
                $new_heading = str_replace(";", "", $line); // Replaces semi-colon
                $new_heading = preg_replace("/\([^\)]+\)/","",$new_heading); //Removes Text With in Brackets
                $line = $new_heading;
                echo $line; //Outputs "Heading: Value1 SomeText1 , Value 2 SomeText2"
                }
```

Now Assume I have a line like this

```
Heading: Text1 (a, b) Text2. (d, f) Text3 (g, h)
```

What I want to achieve is... Remove everything with in brackets (inclusive brackets) and replace it with comma. However the last ocurance of the bracket should not be replace with a comma.

I mean the output should be

```
Heading: Text1 , Text2. , Text3
```

How to achive this?

Comment: It's not possible, the last comma cannot be removed...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you  use two expressions?

```
$text = "Heading: Text1 (a, b) Text2. (d, f) Text3 (g, h)";

$new = preg_replace("/\([^)]*\)(?=.*?\([^)]*\))/",",",$text);
$new = preg_replace("/\([^)]*\)/","",$new);

echo $new . "\n";
```

The first one replaces all instances but the last with commas. The last instance `(g, h)` remains. Then the second expression replaces all remaining instances (which is just one) with an empty string.

Comment: Wow! This is a great idea too. I really wish I could improve more on my RegEx skills. I think only way left for me is to practice, practice and just practice till I get the hang of it.

Comment: In case you haven't run across it yet, http://www.regular-expressions.info/ is the best resource I've found on the subject. RegExr is also a great tool for testing/playing with regexs: http://regexr.com?2u1bh (P.S. If you like an answer, be sure to vote it "up" with the up arrows and pick an answer with the check mark.)

Comment: I wish I could vote up but "Vote Up requires 15 reputation" :(

Comment: Even on answers to your own questions..? That's a little silly...
Try now. =]

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to remove the trailing comma, you could just use substr...

```
$newstr = substr($str, 0, strlen($str)-1);
```

Something like that...

EDIT:>  Ok attempting to answer this again ... Will this work ?

```
$new_heading = preg_replace("/\([^\)]+\)/",",",$new_heading);
$newstr = substr($new_heading, 0, strlen($str)-1);
```

EDIT:>  In response to your comment below.  Thanks :)  I didn't really use a book, just [RegxLib](http://www.regxlib.com/)

Comment: oh no.. I do not want to remove the trailing commas. May be I was not clear?

What I want to do is.. Replace all but the last occurrence of the content of brackets including the brackets with a comma.

In the example I have given input is `Heading: Text1 (a, b) Text2. (d, f) Text3 (g, h)` and the output should be `Heading: Text1 , Text2. , Text3 `

Comment: "However the last ocurance of the bracket should not be replace with a a comma." --user804735

Comment: Well, it sounds like you will have a comma at the end you want to get rid of.  So thought substr might help in your case.  I'm still not really sure what your asking then.  Sorry

Comment: ok no problem, the commas are inside the brackets in the example I have given. I want to replace the whole content of brackets with a comma. 

Input: `Heading: Text1 (a, b) Text2. (d, f) Text3 (g, h)`

Here the items inside the brackets including brackets are `(a, b), (d, f) and (g, h)`. All these should be replaced with a comma instead of the last occurrence. So `(a, b) and (d, f)` will only be replaced with a comma and the last occurrence `(g, h)` will not be replaced.

So the output should be

`Heading: Text1 , Text2. , Text3`

Hope I am clear now.

Comment: `(g, h)` not being replaced seems to contradict when you said "I mean the output should be `Heading: Text1 , Text2. , Text3`" Which do you mean? Do you mean that `(g, h)` should be replaced with nothing? (Technically, this is how you remove things with regex, I believe. "Not replacing it" would mean it's still there.)

Comment: Hey that edited command does work! Thanks.. I wish I could code that fast like you. What book do you use to learn regular expressions? May be I can go through it to get the basics clear. Thanks a lot Brian!

Comment: Hey if this worked can you give me a checkmark?  Im trying to build rep plus you got 7 other super complicated answers after I already answered it for you  :)

Answer (score 1):

(Updated) Try this,

```
$text = "Heading: Text1 (a, b) Text2. (d, f) Text3 (g, h)";

preg_match_all("/\([^\)]+\)/",$text, $brackets);

$bracket_c = count($brackets);

for($bracket_i = 0; $bracket_i < $bracket_c; $bracket_i += 1){
    if($bracket_i == $bracket_c - 1){
        $text = str_replace($brackets[$bracket_i], "", $text);
    }else{
        $text = str_replace($brackets[$bracket_i], ",", $text);
    }
}
echo $text . "\n";
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your time. It does work. The output it gave me:

`Heading: Text1 , Text2. , Text3 , `

I would like this as 

`Heading: Text1 , Text2. , Text3  `

That is, the last occurrence of brackets should not be replaced with a comma.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the definition of [preg_replace()](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) there is a parameter called `$limit`. So here are the steps to solve your problem:

1. use preg_match_all to count the brackets
2. use that number - 1 in the preg_replace and replace the brackets with commas
3. use preg_replace again to replace the last bracket with an empty string

Code:

```
preg_match_all("/\([^\)]+\)/",$new_heading,$matches);
$new_heading = preg_replace("/\([^\)]+\)/",",",$new_heading, count($matches) - 1);
$new_heading = preg_replace("/\([^\)]+\)/","",$new_heading);
```

**Alternative:**

1. use preg_replace as before, but do not store the result. Only use the value of `$count` which is the fifth parameter.
2. use that number - 1 in the preg_replace and replace the brackets with commas
3. use preg_replace again to replace the last bracket with an empty string

Code:

```
preg_replace("/\([^\)]+\)/","",$new_heading, null, $count);
$new_heading = preg_replace("/\([^\)]+\)/",",",$new_heading, $count - 1);
$new_heading = preg_replace("/\([^\)]+\)/","",$new_heading);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$line = 'Heading: Text1 (a, b) Text2. (d, f) Text3 (g, h)';
$line = substr(preg_replace('/\([^\)]+\)/', ',', $line), 0, -1);
?>
```

Or with two regexes you can do:

```
<?php
$line = 'Heading: Text1 (a, b) Text2. (d, f) Text3 (g, h)';
$line = preg_replace('/ \([^\)]+\)$/', '', $line);
$line = preg_replace('/\([^\)]+\)/', ',', $line);
?>
```

But that's overkill. Use one regex for simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

this might look inefficient but will solve your problem. the strategy is

- use `preg_match` to find out the number
  of occurrences of pattern, in this case its brackets and say its
  `n`
- use `preg_replace` to replace the
  occurrences of `n-1` brackets by comma
  setting the `limit` parameter to n-1
- use `preg_replace` to replace the set
  of brackets by empty string

Answer (score 0):

Use code like this:

```
$str = 'Text1 (a, b) Text2. (d, f) Text3 (g, h)';
$arr = preg_split('~\([^)]*\)~', $str, -1 , PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
var_dump(implode(',', $arr));
```

#### OUTPUT

```
string(23) "Text1 , Text2. , Text3 "
```